# Laravel holt a queued job

Tags: laravel, queue, jobs, laravel-9

We are creating an application using laravel like example.com. On our application, there is a post api "example.com/api/order-place". In this api, we store some data on our database and send a successful response to our customer. We also call a third-party application to get some others data (third-party.com/api/get-data) on the same request. We are using a Queue job to get this data, without hampering the main order place request journey.

But sometimes the third-party api service is down. At that time, we want to store that third-party api call in some place (queue) and when the third-party application service is up, we want to process all queued jobs.

How could we achieve this? is it possible to solve this problem using laravel queue? Like when third-party applications are down, we hold our queue, and also when the third-party application is up, process these jobs.

We can do this using queue retry on failed jobs. But don't wants that. We just wants to holt a queue when third-party application is down

Answer (score 0):

Should works like this

1. Create helper function to detect 3rd party api if up or down
2. Create a class or helper function for processing the 3rd party API request, throw an error if the request to 3rd party API fail ( you might want to call **#1**)
3. Create a job with no retries (must only run once) and call **#2** in `handle`
4. Push your Job on different `queue` e.i. `WhatEverJob::dispatch()->onQueue('apirequest');`. You should also process this queue in your supervisor worker e.i

   `php artisan queue:work --queue=default,apirequest`
5. Create a Task Scheduler (cron) that runs every hour, minute or whatever. This should first run **#1** (or query the `failed_jobs` first whatever suits you) and exit if its down, if its up, then proceed to querying the `failed_jobs` table, only pull data with column `queue` value `apirequest`. you can do additional filter with `payload->displayName` which should be your Job Class, you can also check `payload->maxTries` and do something if its more than number of tries. then manually retry each failed entry.

**sample**;

```
if ( ThirdPartyAPI::is('down') )
    return;

$failedEntries = DB::table('failed_jobs') ->where('queue', 'apirequest')->pluck('uuid');

if ( !$failedEntries )
    return;

$uuids = implode(' ', $failedEntries);

\Artisan::call('queue:retry '. $uuids);
```